Runtime Error Error in faiss::Index* faiss::read_index(faiss::IOReader*, int) : Index type 0x73726576 ("vers") not recognized
I saved the index at my local system and wants to use read by using faiss.read_index() method but giving the error. I am using same file that I saved locally.
How to solve this problem is there any different way where we can save the index and use in docker at runtime.
